# Get days between datetime?

Tags: c#

I'm looking to find the days between two datetime values.

On my Linux home machine, it works fine, and returns 13 (rounding up). On the Linux VM ([GCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform)), it's returning -46.

Why is this?

```
Math.Round((DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("10/08/2023 06:00:00")).TotalDays)
```

Comment: October 8th vs. August 10th?

Comment: The date is supposed to represent the 10th August, 2023 yes.

Comment: Where does the date string that you are trying to parse come from? If it is user input, you can use DateTime data type. The .NET model binding should take care of parsing the text.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 13.

Let’s define your two dates (using the datetime from my response) as

- Start = 08/22/2023 11:00:00
- End = 10/08/2023 06:00:00

You are subtracting a previous date from a future date, so you will end up with a negative value. You can run this code or do a fiddle to see the output.

```
    var now = DateTime.Parse("08/22/2023 11:00:00");
    var future = DateTime.Parse("10/08/2023 06:00:00");
    var difference = now - future;
    Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalDays);
```

In this case, you will need to specify the format that you are providing to DateTime. I'm *guessing* that on your local machine (Linux Home Machine) it handles the date time parsing in that specific format you specified, but when you put it on the cloud (Linux VM on GCP) it’s in another format.

You can use DateTime.ParseExact() to specify the format, this below code generates the correct difference.

```
    var now = DateTime.ParseExact("22/08/2023 11:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var futureExact = DateTime.ParseExact("10/08/2023 06:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var differenceExact = now - futureExact;
    Console.WriteLine(differenceExact.TotalDays);
    Console.WriteLine("Rounded: " + Math.Round(differenceExact.TotalDays));
```

This will return 12.208 which you can round however you like.

Comment: You are assuming the funny american date order MM/dd/yyyy, right? The OP seems to have a different culture.

Comment: If that's the case you will need to update the format so you can parse it in a specific way (given the month and day are swapped). I'll update my answer

Comment: @KlausGütter Yeah pretty funny https://www.reddit.com/r/ShitAmericansSay/comments/xyif31/july_4th_which_is_how_i_hear_the_majority_of/

Answer (score -1):

Three actions you can try to find a solution:

- The problem might be in time zones. There is a big chance that your local machine's timezone and the VM's is different and when you use *DateTime.Now* you get that error.
- You can try using UTC. Instead of `DateTime.Now` use `DateTime.UtcNow`.
- If these above suggestions don't work, I advise you to debug and log every single detail you have.